# conda - solving environment taking too long

Tags: python, flask, anaconda, conda

I got stuck on this solving environment when trying to 'conda uninstall flask'. At that time there were a lot of packages that were causing inconsistency. So I read other threads and have already run:
conda update conda
conda update -all

Now when I am trying to 'conda install anaconda', I am getting fewer packages that are causing inconsistency

"
Solving environment: 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

- defaults/win-64::anaconda==custom=py38_1
- defaults/win-64::holoviews==1.16.2=py38haa95532_0
- defaults/win-64::hvplot==0.8.4=py38haa95532_0
- defaults/win-64::panel==0.14.3=py38haa95532_0
- defaults/noarch::python-jsonrpc-server==0.3.4=py_1
- defaults/win-64::python-language-server==0.34.1=py38_0
- defaults/win-64::qt==5.9.7=vc14h73c81de_0
- defaults/win-64::spyder==4.1.4=py38_0
- defaults/win-64::_anaconda_depends==2023.06=py38_0
  failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
  Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
  "

Should I reinstall Anaconda? Or is there a way to solve the inconsistencies of these packages?

I mainly use python in Spyder IDE for data analysis and was trying flask for the first time. I install all packages with conda, but installed tkcalendar with pip.